# Would Palpatine be unable, even if he wanted to, to use the light side of the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, darth-sidious

If we take a look at Palpatine, we can clearly see that he is a sociopath, which means that he is unable to have empathy. The light side of the Force is powered by positive emotions such as compassion. Would it not make Palpatine unable to use the light side of the Force?

Comment: There aren't any powers exclusive to the light side as far as I know. The dark side, however has a lot of powers like choke and lightning.

Comment: There is force heal

Comment: What kind of scope, in terms of canon, are you interested in? Disney-approved canon restricts the conversation quite a lot.

Comment: My layman's understanding is that psychopaths are the ones who don't have empathy for anyone else. Totally self-centered. (I can believe Palpatine might be a psychopath.) Sociopaths are more complicated -- very messed-up, emotionally, but still capable of sometimes caring about certain people enough to feel empathy with them. (In other words, a sociopath might become a serial killer without feeling particularly guilty, but could still feel terrible if something bad happened to one of the few people he actually had a strong emotional bond with.)

Comment: Yes, he did use the Force to help heal Darth Vader's burned body on the trip from Mustafar back to Coruscant. That's a "light" side ability.

Comment: @RichS Source? I'm unaware of a canonical reference to him explicitly using Force Heal there. Not to mention that, even if he were using the Force to preserve Vader, he'd more likely be using [Dark transfer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_transfer), which is a kind of Dark side equivalent. But yeah, source required.

Comment: @RichS You can read [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_healing#Alternate_applications) to learn about what happens when a Dark side force user tries to use Force heal (spoiler alert: it's not pretty)

Comment: @GhotiandChips Palpatine could have used Dark Transfer on Vader then, but I thought it was Force Heal. I'd have to track down the source. Can't remember it right now. :-( On the plus side, you could post a question asking if Palpatine healed Vader right after the duel on Mustafar.

Comment: It's my assumption, using Disney-canon as a scope, that Force Spirit is the only use of Light side of the Force worth discussing. There aren't many canonical things that are exclusive to Jedi, except the ability to become a Force Ghost (which is one of the points in a major character arc of the original trilogy). Other than that, there is no "use" to the Light side, at least canonically, and concretely/practically.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question, we have to establish what we mean by "using the light side of the Force".

Your force alignment affects your weapon, abilities, philosophy/lifestyle and combat stance in the following ways:

- **Weapon:** Jedi craft lightsabers out of kyber crystals which they mine from the planet Ilum.
  Sith get their red variants by pouring their pain and anger into a kyber crystal, which makes it bleed and get its coloration (as we learn in [*Darth Vader #1*](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/63169/darth_vader_2017_1), a canonical comic book).
  The [Kyber crystal article on wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyber_crystal) claims that kyber crystals are inherently attuned to the Light side, and resist Dark side (until submitted and bled), there is nothing stopping a Sith from using a Jedi (non-red) lightsaber effectively. In fact, there are examples of Sith using blue lightsabers, including [Darth Vader](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d3/c0/1a/d3c01a7c75cbd78f6893afaeb7c9ea77--star-wars-saga-behind-the-scenes.jpg), Palpatine (after being reincarnated) and [Exar Kun](http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20080508001107/starwars/images/f/f8/Exar_Kun.jpg), plus their claim about it resisting Dark side users was uncited.
  **Conclusion:** Palpatine would have no problem using light side/Jedi equivalent weapons
- **Abilities:** things like [Force Lightning](http://www.starwars.com/databank/force-lightning) make it very obvious that there are dark side/Sith exclusive abilities, but what about light side/Jedi exclusive abilities? That depends on your canon-scope. If you include [*Star Wars Legends*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_canon) canon, we have things like [Force blinding](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_blinding), [Plant surge](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Plant_Surge), [Wall of light](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_light)...and more. If we consider material that is canon *after* Disney's 2014 reboot, then **we are left with [Force Spirit](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_spirit)** (jokingly and commonly referred to as Force Ghost), and arguably [Force Healing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_healing).
  The technicalities of a lot of this has gone awry, post-reboot, but if we adhere to the movies, it's safe to say that achieving Force Spirit seems to be pretty light side exclusive, considering it's part of Anakin's redemption story arc in the end.
  [image]

Philosophy/lifestyle is quite an abstract topic that would not be appropriate or useful to your question.
As for combat stance, the only real way force alignment affects your combat stance is that [Form VII](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Form_VII), or **Vapaad**, becomes a lot more appropriate if you're a Sith, though it should be noted that it's most notable user was Mace Windu, a Jedi master, so it's by no means a case of exclusivity (and in any case, it would be Sith exclusivity not Jedi), so there isn't much in the way of combat stance that Palpatine would be unable to perform.

According to [the wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_spirit) (not always reliable), Sith are unable to manifest themselves after death:

> Darth Vader learned of this ability through Darth Sidious, and upon his death, the spirits of Kenobi and Yoda completed his training by granting him **the last step** in becoming a spirit.

I should point out that most Jedi, in most of history, didn't know how to manifest themselves after death, and it's possible that it's a case of secrecy maintaining an exclusivity for the Light side (but it's unclear). We can speculate that because the Jedi ethos focuses on harmony, balance, panta rhei (reminiscent of Zen Buddhism), that something like a Force Spirit fits their style, and a Sith's more Earthly desires for power come at a cost of being philosophically blind to potential knowledge about achieving a peaceful death and manifesting as immortal Force Ghosts, so I would conclude that **Palpatine, even if he wanted to, could not become a Force Spirit**.

Comment: Manifesting oneself as a force spirit aside, According to the teachings of the Je'daii Order, Sideous could theoretically change. But I believe that becoming a force spirit came from balance in the force, not the light side. (See the impact that the Whills had on Qui-Gon in becoming a force spirit, and the philosophy of the whills in regards to that of the Je'daii Order).

Answer (score 2):

Boundaries between Light Side and Dark Side are not clearly defined; perhaps such boundaries do not exists. But, from what we know, Light Side is usually associated with compassion, preservation, harmony, keeping things at status quo, lack of (negative) emotions, unselfishness etc ...

Therefore, if Palpatine could act with the Force using afore mentioned motivation, he would use Light Side of the Force, no matter did he consider himself Sith, Jedi or something else . So, could he do it ?  Canon novel "Tarkin", although with convoluted and sometimes illogical plot, had some good parts explaining Sidious's psychology:

> For the Empire, Master.”
>
> “The Empire?” Sidious repeated, miming surprise. “***Since when do you
>   put the needs of the Empire before our needs?***”
>
> Vader crossed his gauntleted hands in front of him. “Our needs
>   supersede all, Master.”

But also this one :

> The power of the dark side coursed through him like a transfusion of
>   unsullied blood.
>
> Out there were people who wished him dead, others who envied his
>   station, and still others who wished merely to be close enough to him
>   to sate themselves on the crumbs he brushed aside. ***The thought of it
>   was almost enough to transform his disgust to sadness for the plight
>   of the ordinary***.

As we can see, Palpatine didn't care much about the Empire, it was just means to an end. Yet, strangely, **he did retain some stumps of empathy inside him**. In his present state of mind he, of course, could not act out of compassion and selflessly. He was not concerned with harmony either, even in his own Empire. Yet, **path to Light Side was still open, even to him**. As long as he lived, there was hope. Unfortunately, unlike Vader, he didn't have anything to attach to, nothing that could pull him from darkness. Or at least, we do not know about such thing. Therefore, he was finally overthrown and consumed by very thing that made him great.